# Light Propagation Volumes interpolation

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, game-engine

I am currently implementing LPV in my engine.

As mentionned [here](http://blog.wolfire.com/2011/03/GDC-session-summary-Battlefield-3-Radiosity) I am supposed to interpolate the values from the octree to obtain smooth colors.

For example check out this picture

[image] 
You have no interpolation (left) and  with interpolation ( right ).

I actually only pick the values from the 3D texture ( octree ) and i obtain the pixelated result:

[image]

### How could I do interpolation to have smooth colors?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no real issue. Single LPV doesn't work over big distances.

For radiosity in large scenes, good options are:

- Cascading LPV in combination with SSGI like in cry engine
- Monte carlo path tracing
- Voxel cone tracing